# Get UTM in android

Tags: android, utm, playmaker

Faced a problem that Play Market does not give utm after installing the ad. I did everything according to the tutorial on getting utm through reciver - the tests work out everything and the receiver works. But if you upload it to the product and the user installs it from advertising in the play market, and not from the site or Google search (of course, from advertising), then the receiver does not work after installation. As I understand it, utm will be transmitted only if the user installs the application using the advertising link from the site or search. Is it even possible to receive utm when a user installs an application for advertising within the Market?

I tried the com.android.installreferrer: installreferrer: 2.2 library, it pulls when installing campaign - goole-play. Now the question is - will it pull utm normally or will it be the same as with the receiver? A very interesting topic - nowhere is there a clear answer, so I asked this question here)